# Как обучить агента в частично наблюдаемой среде?

Tags: машинное-обучение, искусственный-интеллект, информация, обучение-с-подкреплением

Подскажите пожалуйста, нужно обучить агента в частично наблюдаемой среде. Помимо обучения с подкреплением какие ещё существуют методы обучения для частично наблюдаемых сред или для игр с неполной информацией?

Нашёл только "Эволюционные стратегии как масштабируемая альтернатива обучению с подкреплением"